# Image not showing in iPhone 4

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I've taken over a site and for some reason I can't get the image of the credit card logos to show on an iPhone 4. The image shows up and looks great when I test the site on an iPhone 4 on http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ but when I look at it on an actual iPhone 4 the credit cards logos are not there. Using IOS 7.0.2

Here is the code:

```
   <img class="auto auto1" srcset="images/credit-cards-paypal.png  450w, 
                                      images/credit-cards-paypal-350md.png   350w,
                                      images/credit-cards-paypal-200sm.png   200w"
                              src="images/credit-cards-paypal.png" >
```

Here is the page with the CC logos: http://www.oralsurgeons.com/register.php
URL to my style sheet: http://www.oralsurgeons.com/includes/style.css
Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a regular img tag without `srcset` just to see if that's the issue?

Comment: I don't know what causes it to not load, but for browsers that do support `srcset` with `w`, you will want to use the `sizes` attribute as well. Otherwise it defaults to `100vw` which in your case appears too big on a laptop.

Comment: If you just want a fixed-width image you can use `x` instead, which has wider support (although `srcset` *should* be entirely unsupported on iOS 7.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

Normally this version of iOS shouldn't support srcset at all, and therefore shouldn't have been impacted by the presence of srcset :/

Can you please try:

- Add `images/credit-cards-paypal.png 1x,` to the start of the srcset value?
- Removing srcset altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing either the path in your src isn't correct or the name of your non-retina image isn't correct.
I for example forgot a slash in my src path. It might be working in quirk tools because it's loading the srcset image — if your screen's a retina screen — which has the correct data.